# Foiled Game Singleplayer?

Tags: foiled

Is there a single player mode of Foiled where you face an AI instead of having to have another person? I can't find one anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foiled is a 2 player game only.  Sorry.

Comment: forever alone...

Answer (score 1):

If you press enter then up directly after when you click play then press enter again, you will get to a special options menu where you can choose single player mode.
Here is what it looks like:

[image]